# Determine which fields in JSON have been specified

Tags: c#, json, webapi

I'm using WebAPI to to update some entities in the database (.net core 3.0, mvc webapi, efcore, vs2019). I'm having trouble figuring out which properties have actually been sent in JSON request to my webapi endpoint, so I do not update them in the database if they were not sent (i.e. leave them as they are).

Here's my code:

Model:

```
public class UpdateModel
{
   public string FirstName { get; set; }
   public string LastName { get; set; }
   public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

WebAPI method:

```
[HttpPut("entity/{id}")]
public async Task<SomeResult> Update(int id, [FromBody]UpdateModel model)
{
   ...
}
```

Request payload (PUT method, example URL: https://myserver/api/entity/1):

```
{
  FirstName: "John"
}
```

In case with above JSON, only FirstName would get updated in the DB.

If, for example, this JSON was sent:

```
{
  FirstName: "John",
  Address: null
}
```

That would mean that (besides FirstName gets updated) Address would also be updated to null (which wouldn't be in the first case).

There are actually not just string objects in the Model, they are just used here as an example.

My API gets called and everything (with LastName and Address being set to NULL, of course), I just want to know which fields have actually been sent in a JSON request. Must I check every field for NULL value or is there any other method for checking (more generic)?

Maybe there is some other approach to this kind of problem and I'm just not familiar with it?

Comment: “I just want to know which fields have actually been sent” - assuming that a null value and missing field are considered the same, checking for null does just that.. perhaps there is a *different/end* problem that is being solved?

Comment: “Must I check every field for NULL value” - see above and compare with previous quote. It seems like this questions is incomplete. One would check for ‘every’ to know ‘which fields’. Or: perhaps define the the *result* of this check.. eg. is the goal to get a list of field names, as strings, with null (values)?

Comment: I'm curious what you'd really want as a signal that a field is *set* or not. Is there something easier/better than a null check?

Comment: In my case, field specified with null and missing field are not the same. If for example in above code, I would also sent "Address = null" in JSON request, that would mean I want to set Address to null, otherwise leave it as it is. But as I see, null checking is probably the only option.